# Long Layover in Korea

Tags: south-korea

I am a Philippine passport holder and I have a 14 hour layover in Korea on January 29. My problem is that my passport is expiring on April 21. When I called Asiana before I booked my flight, they said that boarding wont be a problem since my final destination is the Philippines and I am not going out of the airport in Korea. However, some people are telling me that Asiana might not board me on the plane because of my passport. Can someone please assure me that I won't have that problem and that I will board smoothly.

Comment: For completeness, what is the point of origin of your journey?

Comment: flying from lax - inc then inc - mnl

Comment: Do you mean ICN? INC is way up in northern China.

Comment: yes. sorry. i meant ICN

Answer (score 2):

Your friends are probably referring to the so-called "six month" rule where some countries require a passport to be valid for six months before accepting it.

The six month rule does not apply to your proposed itinerary. Both Korea and the Philippines accept Philippine passports up to the day of expiry.